# How can search number in string?

Tags: c++, string

Hello? I want to know how can I find number in my string code.
This is my c++ code.

```
    string firSen;
    cout<<"write the senctence : "<<endl;
    getline(cin,firSen);
    int a=firSen.find("pizza");
    int b=firSen.find("hamburger");
    int aa=firSen.find(100);
    int bb=firSen.find(30);
```

I want to write

```
 I want to eat pizza 100g, hamburger 30g!!
```

and I want to know 100 and 30 address.

I know how to find pizza and hamburger address.(It's the right code)

but I don't know how to find number..(I think  int aa=firSen.find(100); int bb=firSen.find(30); is wrong code)

Could you help me?

Comment: `firSen.find("100");` would this work for you?

Comment: Loop into your string and once you got a character that is a number, iterate until your character is not a number anymore. Once you've done that, you have a string that contains a number. After that, you just need to convert your number into a string.

Answer (score 2):

The [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) function takes a `std::string` or a `const char*` as valid search keys.

If you want to search for *'generic numbers'* you'll have to convert them to a `std::string` or use a `const char*` literal

```
 size_type aa=firSen.find("100");
```

or

```
 int num = 100;
 size_type aa=firSen.find(std::to_string(num));
```

<sub>See the [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) function reference</sub>

---

As it looks from your input sample, you don't know the numeric values beforehand, thus looking up something like

```
 size_type aa=firSen.find("100");
```

renders useless.
What you actually need is some decent parser, that enables you reading the numeric values after some certain *keywords*, that require a numeric attribute (like *weight* in your sample).

The simplest way might be, to find your *keywords* like `"hamburger"` or `"pizza"`, and move on from the found position, to find the next digit ('0-9'), and extract the number from that position.

Using [std::regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) as proposed in [@deeiip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27023628/1413395), might be a concise solution for your problem.

Comment: I think the op wants to find any number, not specifically 100 or 30

Comment: @deeiip Well, the information given here should enable them to do it (I've mentioned _`'generic numbers'`_, didn't I?)

Comment: when I dont know how much pizza I'm expecting (say thats what i want to know) how will I know the value of num in your code?

Comment: @deeiip Let's concentrate on what's actually asked in the OP. It's fault of the poster, don't having elaborate on that problem enough. (I'll retract my downvote on your answer)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this in your situation (if I was searching for just a number, not a specific number):

```
std::regex rgx("[0-9]+");
std::smatch res;
while (std::regex_search(firSen, res, rgx)) {
    std::cout << res[0] << std::endl;
    s =  res.suffix().str();
}
```

This is `c++11` standard code using `<regex>`. What it does is: search for any occurence of a number. This is what `[0-9]+` means. And It keep on searching for this pattern in your string.

---

This solution should only be used when I dont know what number I'm expecting otherwise it'll be much more expensive than other solution mentioned.

Comment: I think this is what the op wants. If I'm wrong, yes! my solution is expensive and complex.